# My Toolbar Menu Appears in the Fragment Toolbar

Tags: java, android

I have two `toolbar`, one in my mainActivity, another in my `fragment` and the MenuIteMs of `toolbar` in my mainActivity apper in my `fragment` `toolbar` and i want to exclude the menu in my `Fragment` toolbar.

**Screenshot of my app with two toolbar**:

[image]

**MainActivity**

```
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

        barra_ferramenta = findViewById(R.id.principal_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(barra_ferramenta);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("CME App");
```

**Fragment**

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmento_chat, container, false);

        toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.frag_chat_barra);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar action_bar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();

        action_bar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        LayoutInflater layout_inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view_action_bar = layout_inflater.inflate(R.layout.barra_chat, null);

        action_bar.setCustomView(view_action_bar);
```

Kindly guide me for this.

Thank You

Comment: Don't try set both toolbars as the action bar. Leave the toolbar in fragment just toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set toolbar in Fragment,Remove code from fragment

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmento_chat, container, false);
```

Answer (score -1):

please follow below code

```
   @Override
public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
   super.onStop();
   ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
}
```